# Morningstar expected return

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that I have tweaked below.  I use it to scrape other morningstar data, but I can't seem to make it work now for "expected return" for ETFs(Exchange Traded Funds).  Everything on the code right now is set up to get the data that I need but I am having a problem getting it on the excel spreadsheet.  When I do a msgBox tblTR under the code:

```
Set tblTR = Doc.getElementsByClassName("pr_text3")(4).innerText
```

I get the expected value on the message box.

However, when I take the msgbox code out, the value doesn't appear in the excel spreadsheet.  I have been trying to work it out for hours now and need HELP!

Below is the entire code.  under tab "Tickers2" is where I have all the tickers I would like to pull data.  Examples JKE, JKF, JKD...which I have about 1000.  under tab "ExpectedReturn" is where I want the data to be displayed.  I think it has to do with me pulling elementsbyclassname versus when I used to pull the elementsbytagname.  There wasn't in tagnames in the information i needed so I switched it to class name.  Below is the entire code.

I will also mention that you have to be signed in to morningstar.com in order to get the actual data, but I am assuming that the forum can point me in the right direction without needing to be signed in.

The website is www.morningstar.com

```
Sub ExpectedReturn()

Dim IE As Object, Doc As Object, lastRow As Long, tblTR As Object, tblTD As Object, strCode As String
lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row


Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True


last_row = Sheets("Tickers2").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

ini_row_dest = 1

Sheets("ExpectedReturn").Select

Sheets("ExpectedReturn").Range("A1:H10000").ClearContents

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

For i = 1 To lastRow
    Application.StatusBar = "Updating upDown" & i & "/" & last_row

    row_dest = ini_row_dest + (i - 1)

    strCode = "Tickers2"    ' Range("A" & i).value  
    list_symbol = Sheets("Tickers2").Range("A" & i)
    IE.navigate "http://etfs.morningstar.com/quote?t=" & list_symbol

    Do While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set Doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Set Doc = IE.document

    tryAgain:

    Set tblTR = Doc.getElementsByClassName("pr_text3")(4).innerText

    MsgBox tblTR
    If tblTR Is Nothing Then GoTo tryAgain

    On Error Resume Next



    j = 2
    For Each tblTD In tblTR.getElementsByTagName("td")
        tdVal = Split(tblTD.innerText, vbCrLf)
        Cells(i, j) = tdVal(0)
        Cells(i, j + 1) = tdVal(1)
        j = j + 2



  Next

  Sheets("ExpectedReturn").Range("A" & row_dest).Value = list_symbol
  Next i

    Range("A3").Select

    Application.StatusBar = False

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic


  End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

-Eddie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my fix

```
tblTR=Doc.ElementsByClassName("pr_text3)(4).innerText 
Sheets("ExpectedReturn").Range("B"& row_dest).Value=tblTR
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting

```
Set tblTR = Doc.getElementsByClassName("pr_text3")(4).innerText
```

the variable tblTR is a string. You want a dom element, so remove the *.innerText*

Only then you can loop over its TD-children further down.

Comment: Hey Amadeus.  Thank you for the response.  I was able to fix my problem.
Got rid of the Set when I realized it was a string.

Comment: This was my fix
    tblTR=Doc.ElementsByClassName("pr_text3)(4).innerText
    Sheets("ExpectedReturn").Range("B"& row_dest).Value=tblTR